# How do I use Cloud Functions in firebase to update UI Elements that are populated using data from Cloud Firestore?

Tags: firebase, function, terminal, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cli

I'm very new to coding, and this is my first time using Firebase, so please forgive me for noob questions/language if any. I'd be very thankful for guidance!

I managed to deploy my own fetch function, but what happens is the terminal gives me 2 links- one to a blank web page that shows my Firestore documents, and one that opens up my console.

*My goal is to make relevant changes to Firestore documents from the console itself, then deploy a cloud function, and the end result should be that my app displays a loading page, and then fetches and displays the updated data (ie, the data I added from the console).*

**Basically, is it possible to invoke a fetch() or a get() or a read() function within my app using firebase cloud functions such that the UI changes to reflect the changed Firestore values.**

I'm sure the documentation will provide enough guidance to help me figure out the code myself, I just need to know how I can manage this goal above, and if its possible using cloud functions in firebase.
Thank you!

Comment: I apologise, I reviewed community guidelines and found that this question is actually against guidelines. 
Does anyone know where I can find an answer to this question?

Comment: You can go through this document https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started

Comment: This is largely dependent on how you handle the fetch request client-side in the first place. It's also dependent on the framework you're using. If you were to use `ReactJS` for instance, and wrote your code in such a way that should the value for a certain variable change, it will refresh the page and thus update the UI to show the updated value. Again, this is largely dependent on how you wrote your code and how  you are displaying values. If you could specify the steps you've taken to-date as well as the framework used, perhaps we would be able to help.

Comment: Also, yes you can perform read/write operations on a Firestore instance from a Cloud Function ( provided all authentication steps were taken ). See [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#web_1)